# load image just in src attribute in my site?

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible for the image to be loaded only in `src` with `relative path` and not be directly accessible?

In other words, `<img src="example.jpg" />` would work, but visiting `http://example.com/example.jpg` directly wouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of--you can at least check the referer, and if the referer is not from your site, mark the resource as forbidden:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.com/.*
RewriteRule .*\.jpg - [NC,F]
```

That would serve a forbidden response for any jpg if the referer header is not set to your website.